# How to change UIText field dynamically

Tags: storyboard, uitextfield

I am working on an app, and trying to achieve a different text label message based on the day of week.
ex. if

```
Monday: "Today's Hours are: 8:00am - 6:00pm"
Tuesday: "Today's Hours are: 8:00am - 6:00pm"
Wednesday: "Today's Hours are: 8:00am - 6:00pm"
Thursday: "Today's Hours are: 8:00am - 6:00pm"
Friday: "Today's Hours are: 8:00am - 6:00pm"
Saturday: "Today's Hours are: 9:00am - 2:00pm"
Sunday: "Sorry we are closed today"
```

I have created one label in my storyboard, and want it to change the message based on the day the app is opened.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code in your viewDidLoad method

```
 NSDate* currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSTimeZone* currentTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
NSTimeZone* nowTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];

NSInteger currentGMTOffset = [currentTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:currentDate];
NSInteger nowGMTOffset = [nowTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:currentDate];

NSTimeInterval interval = nowGMTOffset - currentGMTOffset;
NSDate* nowDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:interval sinceDate:currentDate];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
NSString *dayName = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:nowDate];

NSString *timing = @"8:00am - 6:00pm";
NSString *description =@"Today's Hours are";
NSArray *days = @[@"Monday",@"Tuesday",@"Wednesday",@"Thursday",@"Friday",@"Saturday",@"Sunday",];

for (NSString *str in days) {
    if ([str isEqualToString:@"Saturday"]) {
        timing = @"9:00am - 2:00pm";
    }
    if ([str isEqualToString:@"Sunday"]) {
        description = @"Sorry we are closed today";
        timing = nil;
    }
    if ([str isEqualToString:dayName]) {
        NSLog(@"%@ : %@ :%@",str,description,timing);
        //here you can write yourLabelname.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ : %@ :%@",str,description,timing];
    }
}
```

This will give you result  according to current Day

Answer (score 0):

You've got to use an array of strings, with 7 items in it (indexed from 0 to 6), and assign one of its strings to your label's `text` property based on the current weekday.